How to fix userscript to remove SDH portion of subtitles on Amazon Video?
I found a userscript on greasyfork that I am trying to change to function on the Amazon Video website. The script was originally for Netflix and I just changed the class name of the subtitles and it worked for Hulu's site, but for some reason I can't get it figured out for Amazon's site. I've tried various different class names, but none seem to work. I'm pretty positive this is the correct one to target. Element selector of caption box
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Amazon subtitle cleanup
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://www.amazon.com/*
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @description Remove all "[inhales]", "[loud noise]" from the subtitles
// @icon        https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Amazon_icon.svg
// ==/UserScript==

let observed_node = undefined

let kill_song_lyrics = true

const cleanup = (t) => {
  if (kill_song_lyrics && t.includes('♪')) {
    return '' // ignore song lyrics
  } else if (t.includes('[') && t.includes(']')) {
    return t.replace(/(- *)?\[[^\]]+\]/g, '') // (maybe "- ") "[" .. (not "]")+ .. "]"
  } else if (t.includes('(') && t.includes(')')) {
    return t.replace(/(- *)?\([^\)]+\)/g, '') // (maybe "- ") "(" .. (not ")")+ .. ")"
  }

  return t
}

const on_mutated = (changes) => {
  const ts = observed_node.querySelectorAll('atvwebplayersdk-captions-text')
  for (let i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {

    const t = ts[i].innerHTML
    const nt = cleanup(t)

    if (nt !== t) {
      ts[i].innerHTML = nt
      // console.log({ original: t, filtered: nt })
    }
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(on_mutated)

const reobserve = () => {
  const elems = document.getElementsByClassName('atvwebplayersdk-captions-text')
  if (elems[0] !== undefined) {
    if (observed_node !== elems[0]) {
      observed_node = elems[0]
      console.log({ observed_node })
      observer.observe(observed_node, { childList: true, subtree: true})
    }
  }
  window.setTimeout(reobserve, 100)
}


const run_tests = () => {
  // the tests are lightning fast, so just do run them quickly on every script startup
  const test_cleanup = (source, expected) => {
    console.assert(cleanup(source) === expected, { test_result: false, source, expected, actual: cleanup(source) })
  }
  test_cleanup('normal text', 'normal text')
  test_cleanup('[coughs]', '')
  test_cleanup('[coughs] yeah', ' yeah')
  test_cleanup('-[coughs]', '')
  test_cleanup('- [coughs]', '')
  test_cleanup('- (inhales)', '')
  test_cleanup('some ♪ singing', '')
  console.log('tests ok')
}


console.log('Netflix subtitle filter userscript starting up')
run_tests()
reobserve()


